# Radiation therapy

Tags: radiation

I've modelled the volume of a flattening filter of a linear accelerator for radiation therapy. (Which is basically a cone shaped disc of copper or other material). In this modelling I've made an assumption that each voxel of the material has the same contribution to the actual radiation. There are two (to my knowledge) known laws for radiation attenuation. They are the inverse square law, where $\text{intensity} = \frac{1}{(\text{distance}^2)}$. And the $T(x)  \equiv \frac{N(x)}{N(0)} = \exp(-x\mu)$. (Where $x$ is the distance). Does anybody know how to prove that the assumption made is (mathematically) correct?

Thank you very much in advance

Comment: What is the $T(x)$ and $N(x)$ you are talking about ?

Comment: *x* has different meanings in the two equations.  The inverse square law describes the spreading of radiation from a point source, and *x* is the distance from the point source.  The second equation describes the exponential attenuation of radiation passing through an absorber, and *x* is the distance traversed within the absorber.

Comment: what kind of radiation?

Comment: Photon beam radiation

Comment: T(x) = transmission, N(x) = radiation dependent on x

Comment: @David then the next question is: Energy?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$x$ has different meanings in the two equations.  The inverse square law describes the spreading of radiation from a point source, and $x$ is the distance from the point source.  The second equation describes the exponential attenuation of radiation passing through an absorber, and $x$ is the distance traversed within the absorber.

In the case of your flattening filter, distance to a point source really has no meaning so the first equation will not be useful.  The purpose of the filter will be to reduce the beam intensity in the middle of the beam to make the intensity uniform.  If the beam intensity is $I = f(r)$ where $r$ is distance away from the middle of the beam, then you want to use the second equation  $T(x)≡N(x)N(0)=exp(−xμ)$ to find the correct profile of your filter to flatten the beam (it probably won't be exactly conical). $x$ will be a function of $r$ and will represent the height of the filter at different distances $r$ away from the center of the beam.

To avoid confusion, use $h$ as the thickness of the filter.  $h$ is a function of $r$, which is distance from the center of the beam.  Write your second equation as $O(r)/I(r) = exp(-μ h(r))$; $O$ is the output beam intensity as a function of $r$, and $I$ is the input beam intensity as a function of $r$. If you know $I(r)$, you can solve for $h(r)$: $h(r) = (1/μ) ln(I(r) /O(r))$.  You want $O(r)$ to be a constant, and you can't let $h(r)$ go negative.  The bigger $O$ is, the smaller will be the flattened portion of the beam.

Comment: Hi thank you! The intensity of the flattening filter is not the same on every position because of its "cone like shape" meaning the intensity on the top will be higher than the intensity of the beam which "hits" the sides of the flattening filter. But because this doesn't have to travel as far through the filter as photons which "hit" the top, one could assume the contribution to the overall radiation upon "leaving" the flattening filter is location independent. Maybe my formula's aren't correct, would you happen to know a better way to prove this mathematically? Thanks very much in advance

Comment: OK, I added some math.  I think it addresses your question about location independence after leaving the filter: O(r) is constant (out to the edge of the filter).  Try building a spreadsheet with different choices for O, and see where h(r) hits zero. Your output beam can be flattened only out to that radius, given your choice of O.

Comment: The thing is the flattening filter has a scattering contribution to the beam. In my overall model I've taken this into account and in this way the scattering contribution from the flattening filter is based on its volume. The volume is based on the field of view from the (radiated) phantom on the flattening filter and the actual volume itself. This will result in x voxels. I think your way is the same way in which I tried to address the question, but this doesn't seem to solve location independence.

Comment: Scattering adds layers of complexity to the problem, for sure!  An accurate model will need to accommodate the physics of the scattering, which is sure to depend on the energy of the particles in the beam.  You didn't mention what kind of radiation is being used.  Protons and photons, for example, will behave quite differently.  The exponential equation for attenuation is a useful first approximation for x-ray photons, but not for protons.

Comment: I'm trying to model for photon radiation for 6MV and 15MV (for now). For this the most important question is whether it is physically correct (or within a certain margin of error) to assume each volume voxel of the flattening filter has the same scattering contribution to the "output beam" meaning the beam leaving the flattening filter

Comment: You could try reading through this: [https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/3587139] A semianalytical method for the design of a linac x-ray beam flattening filter.

Comment: The link unfortunately doesn't seem to work  (The full text can't be shown while I do have access to that journal).

Comment: As a last resort, you could ask the librarian at a nearby university-- Or contact the authors for the paper directly.